# Loading activity on notification click - activity's UI appears frozen

Tags: android, service, android-notifications

I have an Android app that starts a service, which runs continuously in the background. When this service is started, it creates a pending intent which is suppose to load the main UI, of the app, when the notification is clicked. This works while the phone is active and being used, but if the device is inactive for longer than 30 minutes or so, a strange bug appears after the user clicks the notification. Instead of loading the UI and showing all the buttons, etc. - a black screen appears freezing the app.

Here is how I started the service - incase I'm not starting the service correctly.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
[...]
    public void serviceOn(View view){
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), StableIPService.class));
    }
[...]
}
```

And here is the code from my service

```
public class StableIPService extends Service {
[...]
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Notification notice;
        //The intent to launch when the user clicks the expanded notification
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Build notification
        notice = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("Checking for malicious network connections")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
            .build();

        notice.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        startForeground(myID, notice);
        return (START_STICKY);
    }
[...]
}
```

...and I read somewhere that adding these properties to the AndroidManifest.xml file would help so I added them... It didn't seem to help at all, but here they are.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        [...]
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this issue, check what process you have running that might be building a large queue. In my case, I had a timer set to scheduleAtFixedRate. This meant that when the phone was sleeping (as in the timer wasn't able to execute) tons of timer events were being added to the timer thread queue which, when the phone woke up, caused the app to freeze for awhile as it struggled to complete all backlog of timer tasks.